# Expense account is coming blank in view accounting (Payment Invoice) in oracle apps

Tags: oracle-apps, oracleapplications

Expense account is coming blank in view accounting (Payment Invoice) in oracle apps.

When I checked the view journal entry, I can see one error saying "Code combination is not valid".

I just need an information like from where I can get the expense account which is causing this issue.

I have below information with me:

- Payment Invoice
- Purchase Order number